# How can I use a c++ library in java program using intelliJ IDE on Windows?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-c++, dll

I am not sure about this, but I need help. Is it possible to use c++ library (.lib/.dll) file in java application ?
I am using intelliJ IDE and my application is a JavaFX application. How can I link a this library to my project ?
Need some helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set it up in the [Library configuration dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html?q=java.library.path) as a native library just like as Java library in File | Project Structure | Libraries, choose Add Java Library and select the DLL file.

Note that if you use Maven or Gradle in project for managing libraries then you should use them to set up such libraries too. See e.g. [example for Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-up-jni-development-in-gradle-project.html).